# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError) - Ruby MongoDb

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Always get error:

> wrong argument (given 0, expected 1)

when calling `insert_one` ruby to mongoDB.

I tried to hardcode in the

```
insert_one( { 
      id: "#{id}", 
      showMenu: false, 
      showSub: true, 
      sub: "TSB_02" 
    })
```

I tried to change it to `insert_one(doc.to_json)` and followed solution from stack overflow but still get error. 
I tried to byebug, I got the client & collection, The error always in that line when insert_one.

```
doc = { 
  id: "#{id}", 
  showMenu: false, 
  showSub: true, 
  sub: "TSB_02" 
  }
result = collection.insert_one(doc)
```

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Following [Insert a Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/quick-start/#insert-a-document) in the actual manual might be a good start.

Comment: Sounds like a simple problem to fix but as pointed out, we would need a minimal complete code which breaks.

Comment: In your code, is `collection` a method with one argument?

Comment: I still cant get it done. 
still get that error :(

```(byebug) doc.to_json
"{\"cif\":\"test\",\"showWidget\":false,\"showMenu\":true,\"segment\":\"TSB_02\"}"


(byebug) collection
#<Mongo::Collection:0x70311273146260 namespace=test.db1>


(byebug) collection.insert_one(doc)
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)


(byebug) collection.insert_one(doc.to_json)
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ```collection``` is a access to collection that I followed the tutorial from link above :(

Comment: @RezkiOksaputri: I don't think so. Looks like you're trying this in a debugger in the middle of your app. `collection` might not be what you think it is. Try making an isolated piece of code that we can run ourselves and see the problem. In other words, an MCVE (as mentioned in the first comment by Neil).

Comment: Neill Lunn, Mig, and @SergioTulentsev I run the .rb file on the different part and it works, but when I use it in the cucumber script, it always gives me that error. 
is there any chance that the error because of the cucumber ?

Comment: @RezkiOksaputri: if same exact code works elsewhere, then yes, there's a good chance that it is incompatible with cucumber.